# c# re-throw exception in a method designed to handle exceptions and preserve stacktrace

Tags: c#, exception

I want to write a method that handle exceptions and that will be called inside a `catch` block. Depending on the type of the exception passed, the exception is either passed as an inner exception of a new exception or simply re-thrown. How to preserve stack trace in the second case ?

Example :

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // can throw an exception specific to the project or a .Net exception 
        SomeWorkMethod() 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}

private void HandleException(Exception ex)
{
    if(ex is SpecificException)
         throw ex; //will not preserve stack trace...
    else
         throw new SpecificException(ex);
}
```

What I would not like to do is, because the pattern is repeated in many places and there will be no factorization :

```
try
{
    SomeWorkMethod();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if(ex is SpecificException)
         throw;
    else
         throw new SpecificException(ex);
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use something like "if (!HandleException(ex)) throw;". I know it is not exactly what you want, but it is simple and and not a big deal like the second example.

Comment: Why don't you have a separate catch for the `SpecificException`?  `catch(SpecificException e){throw;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `throw` without specifying the exception to preserve stack trace. This can only be done inside the `catch` block. What you can do is return from `HandleException` without throwing the original exception and then use `throw` right afterwards:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // can throw an exception specific to the project or a .Net exception 
        SomeWorkMethod() 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
        throw;
    }
}

private void HandleException(Exception ex)
{
    if(ex is SpecificException)
         return;
    else
         throw new SpecificException(ex);
}
```

As long as you only use `is` to categorize the exception, the preferred way is two catch blocks:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // can throw an exception specific to the project or a .Net exception 
        SomeWorkMethod() 
    }
    catch (SpecificException)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new SpecificException(ex);
    }
}
```

With C# 6.0 you can also use `when` to let the exception fall through:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // can throw an exception specific to the project or a .Net exception 
        SomeWorkMethod() 
    }
    catch(Exception ex) when (!(ex is SpecificException))
    {
        throw new SpecificException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's a really nice way of doing this in .Net4.5 using [`System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.capture(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception(); //appears to be thrown from here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ThrowEx(ex);
    }

}
public void ThrowEx(Exception ex)
{
    if(someCondition)
    {
        //we're in the scope of a `catch` and the exception
        //is "active", so the exception with original stack-trace
        //can be re-thrown with
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();
        //the following line is unreachable, but the compiler doesn't realise
        //so we can "tell" the compiler that this branch ends in an exception
        //and avoid having to return anything in the non-void case
        throw new Exception(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks spender, you answer very precisely my question. However I had not noticed that there are ways to achieve what I need using many catch blocks (second answer from Sefe).

Comment: @SylvainB. Indeed. The accepted answer is definitely a more appropriate fit to your needs. Your question reminded me that I'd seen this a while back, so it seemed worth sharing.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try this.

```
if(ex.Gettype() == typeof(SpecificException))
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question as far as I can see. Or at least if it does it could do with some added explanation to say how.

Comment: This is wrong in many aspects. Why use reflection? What if `ex` inherits from `SpecificException`? Why not use regular language constructs like `is` (which OP is already doing)?